# Flattening JSON Files for Pizzly Fusion Tables

Tags: python

I am trying to flatten JSON files that come out of the Kallisto -> Pizzly pipeline. The GitHub page provides a python script flatten_json.py (see below). I am still a beginner at python, and haven't been able to figure out how to run this script effectively to generate a gene table. I cannot seem to find any tutorials or vignettes online. Any guidance would be very helpful.

```
import sys
import json
from collections import OrderedDict

####
# gene1_name gene1_id, gene2_name, gene2_id, type, pair, split, txlist

def loadJSON(fn):
    with open(fn) as f:
        JJ = json.load(f,object_pairs_hook=OrderedDict)
    return JJ['genes']

def outputGeneTable(fusions, outf, filters = None):
    outf.write('\t'.join("geneA.name geneA.id geneB.name geneB.id paircount splitcount transcripts.list".split()))
    outf.write('\n')
    for gf in fusions:
        gAname = gf['geneA']['name']
        gAid   = gf['geneA']['id']
        gBname = gf['geneB']['name']
        gBid   = gf['geneB']['id']
        pairs  = str(gf['paircount'])
        split  = str(gf['splitcount'])
        txp = [tp['fasta_record'] for tp in gf['transcripts']]

        outf.write('\t'.join([gAname, gAid, gBname, gBid, pairs, split, ';'.join(txp)]))
        outf.write('\n')

def usage():
    print("Usage: python flatten_json.py fusion.out.json [genetable.txt]")
    print("")
    print("       outputs a flat table listing all gene fusions, if the output file is not")
    print("       specified it prints to standard output")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    nargs = len(sys.argv)
    if nargs <= 1:
        usage()
    else:
        infn = sys.argv[1]
        fusions = loadJSON(infn)
        outf = sys.stdout
        if nargs == 3:
            outf = open(sys.argv[2],'w')

        outputGeneTable(fusions,outf)

        if outf != sys.stdout:
            outf.close()
```

Comment: You can run the script through a Python shell. What troubles you?

Comment: It does not load the json files - I'm not quite sure how it knows the name/locations of these files? It has a sys.argv value of 1 and prints the following: Usage: python flatten_json.py fusion.out.json [genetable.txt]

       outputs a flat table listing all gene fusions, if the output file is not
       specified it prints to standard output

Comment: Use absolute paths for both `.py` script and `.json` file. You also need to provide a third argument for the `txt` file to be created as said in `usage()` function. Actually the `txt` file is optional, choose what's best for you.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Seems so obvious now :)

Comment: When you're learning a new Python package (and the package has good documentation), [`help()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#help) can be your best friend. In any case, you can always mess around on the console until you can get something to work. If the documentation is lackluster, `dir()` might also be able to reveal some important details.